# Still getting a MULTI DELETE error, I have looked at other questions but the issue is still not resolved?

Tags: mysql

I know there is allot of similar questions and I have read them and applied some of the code and understand that to execute a MULTI DELETE you need to join the tables where you are trying to delete from but it is still giving me the same error.

This is the query

```
DELETE supplies
FROM supplies as s 
INNER JOIN supplier as supp ON s.supplierNum = supp.supplierNum
WHERE supplierNum = 'S3';
```

I am trying to delete all information with the supplier number `S3`

The tables are created as follows

```
CREATE TABLE supplier (
      supplierNum CHAR(2)   NOT NULL,
      name CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      status TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
      city VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (supplierNum)
)
```

The supplies table has a composite key

```
CREATE TABLE supplies (
  supplierNum CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  partNum CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  quantity SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (supplierNum, partNum),
  FOREIGN KEY (supplierNum) REFERENCES supplier (supplierNum),
  FOREIGN KEY (partNum) REFERENCES parts (partNum)
);
```

The expected result would be that in both of these tables any supplierNum with the value `S3` will be deleted

> Error message = Error Code 1109. Unknown table `supplies` in MULTI
>   DELETE

Comment: Is the error about ambiguous field reference?  In either case add the exact error message to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you assign  an alias  then use it and avoid ambiguity for columns name

```
DELETE s
FROM supplies  s 
INNER JOIN supplier as supp ON s.supplierNum = supp.supplierNum
WHERE s.supplierNum = 'S3';
```